# "GET" with multiple parameters from angular JS through Web API

Tags: angularjs, web, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to retrieve data from the server, after sending multiple parameters to the server.
this is my Web API Config:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

In my controller I have 2 GET sections:

```
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5

    public List<Object> Get( string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4,
       string p5, string p6, string p7)
    {
      //Do Some Code

    }
```

I want to call the GET with multiple parameters so I do it like this:

```
        self.SearchFunc = function (P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7) {
        var promise = _$http({
            method: "GET",
            url: 'api/Order',
            params: {
                "P1": P1, "P2": P2,
                "P3": P3, "P4": P4,
                "P5": P5, "P6": P6,
                "P7":P7
            }

        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });
        return promise;
    };
```

First of all  is this the right way to send many parametrs in order to get data from the server?
I tried this way, but the debug shows that the code enters the first GET.

Comment: you can use the network tab of google chrome to see the call made to the server. And maybe you can change the name of the method to see if the call works.

Comment: Did what you say, found the problem. Thanks